# to get no. of bytes received and sent in cascades bb 10

Tags: blackberry-10

Im new to cascades programming. Im trying to develop an app that could give me the number of bytes received and sent.
Im using QnetworkSession methods `bytesReceived()` and `bytesWritten()` for it, but getting errors.
Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

**Code**:

```
#include "Monitor.hpp"    
#include <bb/cascades/Application>
#include <bb/cascades/QmlDocument>
#include <bb/cascades/AbstractPane>
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkSession>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkConfiguration>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkConfigurationManager>
using namespace bb::cascades;
QNetworkSession::QNetworkSession ( const QNetworkConfiguration & connectionConfig, QObject * parent = 0 );
Monitor::Monitor(bb::cascades::Application *app)
: QObject(app)
{
    QNetworkSession qnetworksession;
    // create scene document from main.qml asset
    // set parent to created document to ensure it exists for the whole application lifetime
    QmlDocument *qml = QmlDocument::create("asset:///main.qml").parent(this);
    qml->setContextProperty("app", this);
    // create root object for the UI
    AbstractPane *root = qml->createRootObject<AbstractPane>();
    // set created root object as a scene
    app->setScene(root);
}

quint64 Monitor::Received() const
{
    quint64 rec=qnetworksession.bytesReceived ();
    return(rec);
}


quint64 Monitor::Sent() const
{
    quint64 sen=qnetworksession.bytesWritten ();
    return(sen);
}
```